# Force InfluxDB to listen on localhost only

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to get InfluxDB v1.1.1 to listen on localhost only AND work with both IPv4/v6. Server is running on Debian 7.

Default, config, I can reach influx internally and externally:

```
[http]
  # The bind address used by the HTTP service.
  bind-address = ":8086"

netstat -antp | grep "influx"
tcp6       0      0 :::8083                 :::*                    LISTEN      813/influxd     
tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                    LISTEN      813/influxd     
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      813/influxd     

curl -4 -sl -I localhost:8086/ping <- Works
curl -6 -sl -I localhost:8086/ping <- Works
```

Attempting to listen on localhost only using IPv6 I cant reach influx internally or externally using IPv4/IPv6:

```
[http]
  # The bind address used by the HTTP service.
  bind-address = "[::1]:8086"

  netstat -antp | grep "influx"
tcp6       0      0 :::8083                 :::*                    LISTEN      1831/influxd    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8086                :::*                    LISTEN      1831/influxd    
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      1831/influxd

curl -4 -sl -I localhost:8086/ping <- Does not work
curl -6 -sl -I localhost:8086/ping <- Does not work
```

Attempting to listen on localhost only using IPv4 I can reach influx internally using IPv4 only:

```
[http]
  # The bind address used by the HTTP service.
  bind-address = "127.0.0.1:8086"

  netstat -antp | grep "influx"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8086          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3375/influxd    
tcp6       0      0 :::8083                 :::*                    LISTEN      3375/influxd    
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      3375/influxd  

curl -4 -sl -I localhost:8086/ping <- Works
curl -6 -sl -I localhost:8086/ping <- Does not work
```

Not sure if I am missing something in the config or if this is just not possible.

Comment: Currently, this isn't possible with InfluxDB. I'd encourage you to open a [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/new) on InfluxDB, or check out the [influxdb community](https://community.influxdata.com/) to see if there are any work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to [have been solved](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/9736#issuecomment-383231890) in April 2018. TL;DR: use bind-address twice, once at the top (for backups/diagnostics access to influxdb) and once for the HTTP API:

```
bind-address = "127.0.0.1:8088"

[http]
  bind-address = "127.0.0.1:8088"
```